# clearTimeout() inside setTimeout() method not working in JS

Tags: javascript, timer, settimeout

`clearTimeout()` inside `setTimeout()` method not working in JavaScript

```
var c = 0;
var t;

function timedCount() {
    document.getElementById('txt').value = c;
    c = c + 1;
    if (c == 5) {
        clearTimeout(t);
    }
    t = setTimeout(function () {
        timedCount()
    }, 1000);
}
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/askkathir/SEGtY/5/)

Comment: It does "work", but your logic is incorrect. After you called `clearTimeout` you are calling `setTimeout` again. Instead of calling `clearTimeout` you should just exit the function.

Comment: See here as @Felix pointed http://jsfiddle.net/SEGtY/7/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to prevent the rest of the code of executing, actually you are re-declaring `t` after clearing the `setTimeout`. [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bVFd2/)

```
var c = 0;
var t;

function timedCount() {
    document.getElementById('txt').value = c;
    c = c + 1;
    if (c == 5) {
        clearTimeout(t);
        return false;
    }
    t = setTimeout(timedCount, 1000);
}
```

Or just use the `else` statement:

```
if (c == 5) {
  clearTimeout(t);
  // do something else
}else{
  t = setTimeout(timedCount, 1000);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There will never be a timeout to clear when you call `clearTimeout` as the last one will have already fired and the next one won't have been set yet.

You want to change your logic so that `if (c !== 5) { setTimeout(etc etc) }`